# comparing if time is greater than zero

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

i have a code that i want to execute if time is greater than zero.i have tried almost all the solutions from stackoverflow but did not get my desired result.
i have tried so far

```
$query="select TIMEDIFF(date_and_time,NOW()) as time_remaining from exam_schedule";//query to get remaining time from database


if($remaining_time>0)
//run script
else
redirect to another page

if((int)$remaing_time>0)
//run script 
else 
redirect to another page

if($remaing_time>strtotime('00:00:00'))
//run script 
else 
redirect to another page


 if($remaing_time>mktime(0,0,0))
 //run script 
 else 
 redirect to another page
```

i am getting `$remaing_time` from database . its the difference b/w (current and stored time) i.e `stored_time=10:30` ,`current_time 10:20`, `remaining_time=00:00:10`

Comment: What value does `$remaining_time` contain?

Comment: i am getting this from database . so it contain string values of time.

Comment: and _what_ contains?

Comment: it contains values in this format 00:00:00

Comment: What about saving the Unix timestamp in the db and then use `time()` in php and compare these values?

Comment: full code next time, it could be how you run the query - but we don't know

Comment: @eexamilm Tell us the type of the variable please. gettype — Get the type of a variable: `echo gettype($remaing_time)`

Comment: @mertyildiran its string type variable.

Comment: @eexamilm This will be enough: `if (strtotime($remaing_time) > strtotime('00:00:00')) {
        echo "True";
}`

Comment: I don't see the execution of the query.

Comment: @Federico it contains the difference of two times. but it is string type variable

Answer (score 1):

Use [TIME_TO_SEC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to turn an `HH:MM:SS` string into seconds.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(date_and_time,NOW())) AS time_remaining FROM exam_schedule
```

Then do

```
if ($remaining_time > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

All i need was

```
$remaining_time > "00:00:00"
```

because `$remaining_time` is a string type variable.